# How would I change a string of text within a formula using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a program that will find and replace values within a directory containing multiple excel files. I've gotten it to work with all cell values in each workbook, but it isn't changing the text strings within formulas...

```
    '# USED TO FIND AND REPLACE VALUES IN EACH WORKBOOK IN A DIRECTORY
        Dim ws2 As Worksheet
        Dim findList As Variant, replaceList As Variant
        Dim x As Long
        Dim find1 As String, find2 As String, find3 As String
        Dim replace1 As String, replace2 As String, replace3 As String
        
            find1 = ws.Cells(4, 2)
            find2 = ws.Cells(7, 2)
            find3 = ws.Cells(10, 2)
                replace1 = ws.Cells(5, 2)
                replace2 = ws.Cells(8, 2)
                replace3 = ws.Cells(11, 2)
        
                    If find2 = "" Then
                        findList = Array(find1)
                        replaceList = Array(replace1)
                        
                    ElseIf ws.Cells(10, 2) = "" Then
                        findList = Array(find1, find2)
                        replaceList = Array(replace1, replace2)
                        
                    Else
                        findList = Array(find1, find2, find3)
                        replaceList = Array(replace1, replace2, replace3)
                    End If
        
            '# Loop through each item in Array lists
                For x = LBound(findList) To UBound(findList)
                    For Each ws2 In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                      ws2.Cells.Replace What:=findList(x), Replacement:=replaceList(x), _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
                    Next ws2
                Next x
```

The portion of the worksheet formula I am looking to change is bolded below:

=@SUBNM("**eh_operating_budget_2022-23**:Budget Adjustment Number","","")

I've tried looking in formulas and what not and changing the MatchCase / LookAt / and removed the FormulaVersion, nothing is working.

Comment: For starters, `LookAt:=xlWhole` won't work if you're considering just part of a string.

Comment: Ok, I never knew that... But the issue that presents is it changes just the last portion of the string 2022-23 because that is another value that is being found and replaced with the macro. Only way I was able to prevent that was using xlWhole, but that makes sense.. Thank you,

Comment: Are you trying to [update workbook links](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/update-workbook-links-21e995b5-bab1-4328-8ab3-dd357fe0e653)? If so, there's a better way to that in VBA than `Replace`.

Comment: Basically I need to roll-forward ~ 50 workbooks from a previous year to the current year. So I need to change specific values that differ in each... The point of the macro was so that I didn't have to open each workbook and Ctrl+H each.